# Efficiency of the modulo operator for bounds checking

Tags: optimization

I was reading [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973852.aspx) on operation performance in .NET and saw there's a really huge difference between the division operation and the rest.

Then, the modulo operator is slow, but how much with respect to the cost of a conditional block we can use for the same purpose?

Let's assume we have a positive number `y` that can't be >= 20. Which one is more efficient as a general rule (not only in .NET)?

This:

```
x = y % 10
```

or this:

```
x = y
if (x >= 10)
{
    x -= 10
}
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: the second code snippet is inherently unsafe and less clear. What if the code usage changes and y can be greater 20. What concerns you more: correct code or micro-optimisation?

Comment: I am using J2ME (1.4.2). Mitch: yeah, I know the second code snippet is not really nice, but at the moment I was concerned about micro-optimization, if there was a general rule for that.

Answer (score 0):

How many times are you calling the modulo operation? If it's in some tight inner loop that's getting called many times a second, maybe you should look at other ways of preventing array overflow. If it's being called < (say) 10,000 times, I wouldn't worry about it.

As for performance between your snippets - test them (with some real-world data if possible). You don't know what the compiler/JITer and CPU are doing under the hood. The `%` could be getting optimized to an `&` if the 2nd argument is constant and a power of 2. At the CPU level you're talking about the difference between division and branch prediction, which is going to depend on the rest of your code.

Comment: Yeah, I was concerned about the difference at CPU level between division and branch misprediction. What if the second argument's not a power of 2?

At the moment it's not a concern in my code, I was just asking the question out of curiosity in case there was a general rule.